# Joda Time IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jodatime

I use Joda Time Framework. In My function i do this:

```
...
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime(DateTime.now().toString());
...
```

i have this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format:
>   "2016-03-11T11:38:22.666+01:00" is malformed at
>   "16-03-11T11:38:22.666+01:00"

What's wrong ..?

***Update:***

I use the @user2004685 code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime newTime = formatter.parseDateTime(new Date().toString());
Date startDate =  newTime.toDate();
newTime = formatter.parseDateTime(DateTime.now().plusMonths(6).toString());
Date endDate = newTime.toDate();
```

i have this new error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Fri Mar 11
>   12:09:36 CET 2016"

Comment: @user2004685 when i use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` i have this error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2016-03-11T11:44:08.187+01:00" is malformed at "T11:44:08.187+01:00" `

Comment: Try using `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Comment: Dear gentlemen, if you downvote please give at least a small comment how my answer can be improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your string should be in same format if you want to parse it. Right now you are creating the String out of Date which will be in `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy` format but you are using a different format i.e. `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Here is the code snippet:

```
DateTimeFormatter out = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
DateTime newTime = out.parseDateTime(new Date().toString());
```

If you want to convert this Date into `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format then you can further do something like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter in = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(in.print(newTime));
```

Comment: there is an error `The method parseDateTime(String) in the type DateTimeFormatter is not applicable for the arguments (Date)` on your line `DateTime newTime = out.parseDateTime(new Date());`

Comment: @Mercer Sorry it should be `new Date().toString()` instead of just `new Date()`. Updated the solution.

Comment: You forgot to change the Pattern.

Comment: I do not understand what I forgot ..?

Comment: Why are you using `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` as the pattern instead of `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106001/discussion-between-mercer-and-user2004685).

Comment: I'm not able to join the chat. Seems like it has been restricted by my company.

Comment: i use a framework who need Date at the entry `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.CalendarView.CalendarView(Date startDate, Date endDate)`

Comment: Okay. So what is the problem?